# How to implement a Summary API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that uses the Aylien Summarizer API to summarize the current webpage. I made my manifest with the permissions for the current tab. I have a popup.html, which is the display for the extension icon and the button it creates. Then I have a popup.js that contains all the logic and calls to the API. I can't figure out how to use the API I'm working with and how to display the data it returns. I'm thinking about creating a form and populating it with the sentences the API returns.

This is the documentation for the API I'm using: http://docs.aylien.com/docs/summarize

**Popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aylien Summarizer</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Aylien Summarizer</h1>
    <input type="button" onclick="summarizeNow()" value="Summarize now!"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Popup.js**

```
function summarizeNow() {
    var AYLIENTextAPI = require('aylien_textapi');
    var textapi = new AYLIENTextAPI({
    application_id: "12049eaa",
    application_key: "0050eee15d54ac3dbd69d868fc1e8570"

    var current = window.location.href 

    textapi.summarize({
      url: 'current',
      sentences_number: 5
    }, function(error, response) {
      if (error === null) {
        response.sentences.forEach(function(s) {
          console.log(s);
        });
      }
    });
    });
}
```

So I'm thinking about adding this somewhere into the above foreach loop:

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
f.appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a div in your HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aylien Summarizer</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Aylien Summarizer</h1>
    <input type="button" onclick="summarizeNow()" value="Summarize now!"/>
    <div id="summary"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and append to that in the loop:

```
function summarizeNow() {
    var AYLIENTextAPI = require('aylien_textapi');
    var textapi = new AYLIENTextAPI({
    application_id: "12049eaa",
    application_key: "0050eee15d54ac3dbd69d868fc1e8570"

    var current = window.location.href
    var sum = document.getElementById("summary"); 

    textapi.summarize({
      url: 'current',
      sentences_number: 5
    }, function(error, response) {
      if (error === null) {
        response.sentences.forEach(function(s) {
        sum.innerHTML = sum.innerHTML + s;
        });
      }
    });
    });
}
```